# Inflate from layout-v10 folder on a hdpi gingerbread device?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having both layout folders "layout-v10" and "layout-hdpi" in my application. However, as some gingerbread(which is API Level 10) devices also are hdpi screen size, the layouts under the "layout-hdpi" folder is getting inflated. I want to force the layout from "layout-v10" folder to be inflated for all gingerbread devices even if it is a hdpi. Is there any way to do so?

I read this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html couldn't figure out what can be done to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

to keep layouts looking good in all devices we don't provide folders like "layout-hdpi", etc.
U need to keep your resources in drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, etc. as mentioned in the android developers guide. The android system chooses the correct folder based on the screen density. This works independent of the api version you are using, the layout will look good in all api levels if you are defining your resources correctly acc. to different screen densities.